# Problem getting which switch was changed (UISwitch as accessory type)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiswitch

I need help figuring out which Accessory Type Switch has been changed.

I have a list of games in a UITableView.  I've added a UISwitch as an accessory type, and each switch reacts to touch, changing its state and notifying its action receiver.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if(nil == cell){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

}


Games *games=[appDelegate.hidden objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = games.gameName;

//the switch is defined here, as is its target-action

testSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 74.0, 27.0)];
[testSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(button_Clicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//If I used the tags
    testSwitch.tag=indexPath.row;

[testSwitch setOn:YES];
cell.accessoryView=testSwitch;


[games release];

return cell;
}
```

And the target-action: see comments

```
- (void)button_Clicked:(id)sender{
    UISwitch* switchControl = sender; //if I make this an int, the switches 
                //have different numbers.  If it's cast as a string, it's gobbledegook.

//This always returns 0.  I can't tell it it's not getting anything (ie it's 
                // nil), or if the row always comes up 0.

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *x=[table indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"%i",x.row);


}
```

I see two potential problems.  One, I need to make a switch for every row, uniquely named. Two, I'm not getting the cell correctly.

If anyone can see my mistake(s), any help is welcome.

I've looked through everything I can find on stackoverflow, and several pages into 5 or 6 different search queries on Google, the two above examples in the target-action method are the best I've found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

set a tag like `testSwitch.tag = indexpath.row` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

then in your button clicked event

```
UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

int row = tswitch.tag;

NSlog(@"Your selected array value :%@",[your array objectatindex:row]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer.  I missed the line "UISwitch *tswitch=(UISwitch *)sender;" so every time I tried to access the tag with testSwitch.tag I got the last initialization of testSwitch, rather than the switch activating the trigger.

Comment: Lol it wouldn't let me until I'd waited a minute.  Done!

Comment: It never hurts to wait a little to accept an answer... some better ones may happen along after a little while. For example, you don't retain `games`, so you shouldn't release it. Also, it'd be smart to create the switch in the `if (cell == nil) {...` block and then just reset its state and tag outside the block -- that way you're not constantly creating new switches.